# UITableView Row Heigh Changing Between Scenes (swift)

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a tableview set up to load from an array. I want the first item to show in the table as the "user's profile" so the height is set differently from the other cells like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //some conditional to see which cell we use

    //if it's the first cell make it the profile cell - basic cell
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        //set the height
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 230.0

        //call the profile cell
        return basicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    } else //do they have friends?
        {
        //set the height
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 70.0

        //get the friend var
        let item: String = TableDataFriends[indexPath.row]

        if(item=="nofriends") {
            //no friends. Tell them to invite some
            return inviteCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        } else {
            //got friends. Show them with the friend cell with image
            return imageCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when the page loads initially, however when I navigate from the table page to any other scene and then back, all cell heights are 70 and the "profile cell" is now merged layered behind the other cells. I've tried a few different things to ensure that the height is set up properly. The below two functions I tried did nothing.

```
//test for table height
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if(indexPath==1) {
        return 230.0
    } else {
        return 70.0
    }

}


//test for table height
func configureTableView() {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 230.0
}
```

How do I make sure the first cell's height stays at 230 and the others remain at 70 between page navigation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented variable row heights by overriding the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`.  You were on the right track with 
`tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

A note about what you attempted in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` override:  The `rowHeight` property applies to all rows in the `tableView`, so while you think you're changing it for one row, you're actually changing it for all of them.

Comment: I was able to fix it using your suggestions. I've updated my code with the full answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath==0) {
            return 230.0
        } 
    else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension 
     }

   }
```

You need not specify anything related to height in cellForRowAtIndexPath .

Comment: It's strange, I did this but all rows are around 70 meaning indexPath at 0 is never 230. Any idea how this could be?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is add the following and remove the rowHeight.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let ix = indexPath.row

    if ix == 0 {
        return 230.0
    }
    else {
        return 70.0
    }

}
```